# sorting a specific group of items in a nested list

Tags: python

```
students = [["White", "Snow", 9, "F", 3.56],
            ["Sprat", "Jack", 12, "M", 2.0],
            ["Contrary", "Mary", 9, "F", 3.674],
            ["Dumpty", "Humpty", 11, "M", 2.342],
            ["Bunny", "Easter", 10, "M", 4.233],
            ["Wonderland", "Alice", 10, "F", 3.755],
            ["Bunyon", "Paul", 11, "M", 1.434],
            ["Penny", "Henny", 9, "F", 2.54],
            ["Hatter", "Mad", 11, "M", 4.522],
            ["Munk", "Chip", 10, "M", 3.0],
            ["Hood", "Red Riding", 10, "F", 3.137],
            ["Bunny", "Bugs", 11, "M", 2.12],
            ["Duck", "Daffy", 11, "M", 3.564],
            ["Ant", "Atom", 12, "M", 3.333],
            ["Mouse", "Mickey", 10, "M", 3.975],
            ["Brown", "Charlie", 9, "M", 1.25]]
```

Here I have five different lists in a nested list.  How would I sort the last column (5th) but not the whole nested list?

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: sorted from least to greatest.

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: Hey `Raleigh Clemens`! Welcome to stackoverflow. Make sure when you ask a question to show some effort in what you have attempted so far. Most people wont bother to answer a question if you have not at least attempted to solve it yourself. If you do get an answer that solves you problem (see my answer below :D ) then make sure you upvote and accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: When I type     sorted(students, key = lambda x:x[-1])
                        for entry in students:
                            a, b, c, d, e = entry
                            print(a, b, c, d, e)    the last column of the list is still not sorted.

Comment: thank you bacontech I upvoted you

Comment: make sure to select the check mark next to the answer that best solves your problem. This will help others find the solutions they are looking for who come to this thread with a like problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after:

```
#sort list by last element
sorted(students,key=lambda x:x[-1])
Out[155]: 
[['Brown', 'Charlie', 9, 'M', 1.25],
 ['Bunyon', 'Paul', 11, 'M', 1.434],
 ['Sprat', 'Jack', 12, 'M', 2.0],
 ['Bunny', 'Bugs', 11, 'M', 2.12],
 ['Dumpty', 'Humpty', 11, 'M', 2.342],
 ['Penny', 'Henny', 9, 'F', 2.54],
 ['Munk', 'Chip', 10, 'M', 3.0],
 ['Hood', 'Red Riding', 10, 'F', 3.137],
 ['Ant', 'Atom', 12, 'M', 3.333],
 ['White', 'Snow', 9, 'F', 3.56],
 ['Duck', 'Daffy', 11, 'M', 3.564],
 ['Contrary', 'Mary', 9, 'F', 3.674],
 ['Wonderland', 'Alice', 10, 'F', 3.755],
 ['Mouse', 'Mickey', 10, 'M', 3.975],
 ['Bunny', 'Easter', 10, 'M', 4.233],
 ['Hatter', 'Mad', 11, 'M', 4.522]]
```

Comment: Yes. How did you get there?

Comment: key=lambda x:x[-1] tells the sorted function to sort the outer list based on the last element in your inner list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use itemgetter.

Try the following:
EDIT: Changed to a function that prints out the sorted list on each line.

```
from operator import itemgetter

students = [["White", "Snow", 9, "F", 3.56],
            ["Sprat", "Jack", 12, "M", 2.0],
            ["Contrary", "Mary", 9, "F", 3.674],
            ["Dumpty", "Humpty", 11, "M", 2.342],
            ["Bunny", "Easter", 10, "M", 4.233],
            ["Wonderland", "Alice", 10, "F", 3.755],
            ["Bunyon", "Paul", 11, "M", 1.434],
            ["Penny", "Henny", 9, "F", 2.54],
            ["Hatter", "Mad", 11, "M", 4.522],
            ["Munk", "Chip", 10, "M", 3.0],
            ["Hood", "Red Riding", 10, "F", 3.137],
            ["Bunny", "Bugs", 11, "M", 2.12],
            ["Duck", "Daffy", 11, "M", 3.564],
            ["Ant", "Atom", 12, "M", 3.333],
            ["Mouse", "Mickey", 10, "M", 3.975],
            ["Brown", "Charlie", 9, "M", 1.25]]

def printSortedStudents():
    sortedStudents = sorted(students, key=itemgetter(4))
    # You can change the index value of itemgetter(4) to define what index to sort with.
    for l in sortedStudents:
        print (l)

printSortedStudents()
```

The result should look something like this:
The function is sorting by the number in the last value of each list.

```
['Brown', 'Charlie', 9, 'M', 1.25]
['Bunyon', 'Paul', 11, 'M', 1.434]
['Sprat', 'Jack', 12, 'M', 2.0]
['Bunny', 'Bugs', 11, 'M', 2.12]
['Dumpty', 'Humpty', 11, 'M', 2.342]
['Penny', 'Henny', 9, 'F', 2.54]
['Munk', 'Chip', 10, 'M', 3.0]
['Hood', 'Red Riding', 10, 'F', 3.137]
['Ant', 'Atom', 12, 'M', 3.333]
['White', 'Snow', 9, 'F', 3.56]
['Duck', 'Daffy', 11, 'M', 3.564]
['Contrary', 'Mary', 9, 'F', 3.674]
['Wonderland', 'Alice', 10, 'F', 3.755]
['Mouse', 'Mickey', 10, 'M', 3.975]
['Bunny', 'Easter', 10, 'M', 4.233]
['Hatter', 'Mad', 11, 'M', 4.522]
```